# Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing

Tags: react-native

I have two flows in my app in the main flow.. one is stack navigation and the other is drawer navigation. Stack navigation is working okay but drawer one is giving me this error -

Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In `react-navigation` version 3 you must set up your app container directly. More info: 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html

**App.js**

```
import { createAppContainer,
         createStackNavigator , 
         createBottomTabNavigator,
         createDrawerNavigator,
         createSwitchNavigator
       } from "react-navigation";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./src/screens/RegisterScreen";
import StartScreen from './src/screens/StartScreen';
import { HomeDrawerNavigator } from "./src/components/HomeDrawerNavigator";

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    loginFlow: { 
      screen: createStackNavigator(
        {
          StartScreen :{screen:StartScreen
            },
          LoginScreen : {screen : LoginScreen},
          RegisterScreen : {screen : RegisterScreen}
        }
      )
    },
    homeflow: {
      screen:HomeDrawerNavigator
    }

  }
)



const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default App;
```

**HomeDrawerNavigator.js**

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import PolicyScreen from "../screens/PolicyScreen";

export const HomeDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  PolicyScreen: { screen: PolicyScreen }
})
```

I have also added  `<HomeDrawerNavigator/>` component in my `Homescreen.js`.